# Symfony2, Doctrine, How set datetime to Entity

Tags: datetime, symfony, doctrine

i can not understand how can i persist datetime to database. I have string

```
    (string) $oXml->currentTime
```

actually it's not a string but we convert it, so how can i add it to entity without error

```
    Fatal error: Call to a member function format() on a non-object in...
```

current code

```
    $currentTime = \DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:m:s', (string) $oXml->currentTime);
    $cachedUntil = \DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:m:s', (string) $oXml->cachedUntil);

    $oApiKeyInfo
            ->setCurrentTime($currentTime)
            ->setCachedUntil($cachedUntil)
```

not working :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass the a DateTime object. Create it with a new statement, you can specify the time to use with the first constructor parameter.

```
$currentTime = new \DateTime((string) $oXml->currentTime);
$cachedUntil = new \DateTime((string) $oXml->cachedUntil);

$oApiKeyInfo->setCurrentTime($currentTime)
  ->setCachedUntil($cachedUntil);
```

If you need to specify a Timezone you can use the DateTimeZone class and pass it as the second parameter to the DateTime constructor.

Comment: thnx solution was in "set timezone"